# How can i initialize variables in a class in a single file without the statefulwidget?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have created a class in a single separated file where I have a StraemSubscription function to listen to my current position updates as I move (tracking position).

When I tried to call the function from the full_screen_map file to draw the marker and position updates. I get an initialize error on both the latitude and longitude in my LocationTrack class.

I would like to know how can i initialize them both since I'm not in a stateful widget and cannot use the IniState(){} to initialize them. I tried using a '?' at the end of double but the LatLng() function in the full_screen_map cannot take null values.

if more details are needed in order to fix this issue I will provide them. I was thinking about just extracting the class from its single file and having everything inside the full_screen_map file to take advantage of the InitState(){} but it seems like I would just be running from the problem. I want to learn how can i fix it or bypass this problem for future reference.

`

```
class LocationTrack {
  late double latitude;
  late double longitude;
  late LocationSettings locationSettings;
  StreamSubscription<Position> getTrackingLocation() {
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      locationSettings = AndroidSettings(
          accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
          distanceFilter: 10,
          forceLocationManager: true,
          intervalDuration: const Duration(seconds: 10),
          //(Optional) Set foreground notification config to keep the app alive
          //when going to the background
          foregroundNotificationConfig: const ForegroundNotificationConfig(
            notificationText:
                "Example app will continue to receive your location even when you aren't using it",
            notificationTitle: "Running in Background",
            enableWakeLock: true,
          ));
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS ||
        defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS) {
      locationSettings = AppleSettings(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
        activityType: ActivityType.fitness,
        distanceFilter: 10,
        pauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically: true,
        // Only set to true if our app will be started up in the background.
        showBackgroundLocationIndicator: false,
      );
    } else {
      locationSettings = const LocationSettings(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
        distanceFilter: 10,
      );
    }

    return Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: locationSettings)
        .listen((Position position) {
      latitude = position.latitude;

      longitude = position.longitude;
      // do what you want to do with the position here
    });
  }
}
```

`

Comment: Hi, Does the  full_screen_map file has the latitude and longitude values?

Comment: Yes, I have the class initialized>> LocationTrack locationTrack = LocationTrack() and then assigning the latlng >> LatLng(locationTrack.latitude, locationTrack.longitude)--- i am able to get my current location, im just not able to listen to the stream updates since the latitude n longitude needs to be initialized on the module where i have the solo class.

Comment: So, I guess you can try to initialize the values in the LocationTrack constructor. Just try removing the late keyword at the definition, and define a constructor like LocationTrack ({required this.latitude, required this.longitude}).

Comment: Thank you for your replies. This gave me hope but when I used the locationTrack in the full_screen_map it still asking me to provide the latitude n longitude since i made it a requirement to be fed to the locationTrack.

Comment: Always, but maybe if you provided the full_screen_map code and the section you are initializing the LocationTrack constructor it would be easier to understand the code and the problem.